# Show that the solutions to differential equations are the same - decomposition property

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

Consider a linear and time-invariant system with differential equation $Q(D)y(t) = P(D)x(t)$
where $Q(D)$ and $P(D)$ are differential operator polynomials.

We define the **zero-state response** as the solution to this differential equation with all initial conditions set to $0$

$$Q(D)y_{zs}(t) = P(D)x(t) \tag{1}.$$

We define the **zero-input response** as the the solution to this differential equation with non-zero initial conditions

$$Q(D)y_{zi}(t) = 0 \tag{2}.$$

The decomposition property for linear systems states that the solution to $(1)$ plus the solution to $(2)$ is the same as the solution to

$$Q(D)[y_{zs}(t)+y_{zi}(t)] = P(D)x(t) $$

with non-zero initial conditions.

**My question is** why is this true? How can one show that the decomposition holds for any linear system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $y_{zs} + y_{zi}$ satisfies the initial conditions, so we just need to show that it also satisfies the differential equation:
$$
Q(D)[y_{zs}(t) + y_{zi}(t)] = Q(D) y_{zs}(t) + Q(D)y_{zi}(t) = P(D)x(t) + 0 = P(D) x(t)
$$

By uniqueness of solution, if $y_{zs}+y_{zi}$ satisfies the differential equation and the initial conditions, we must have that $y = y_{zs}+y_{zi}$.

Comment: Can you explain why $y_{zi} + y_{zs}$ satisfy the initial conditions? And can you put some more words on the “uniqueness of solution” theorem?

Comment: @Carl The zero state solution has zero initial conditions, while the zero input solution has the same initial conditions as the full equation. For instance, $y_{zs}(t_0) = 0$ and $y_{zi}(t_0) = y_0$ where $y_0$ is the initial condition. So, $y_{zs}(t_0)+y_{zi}(t_0) = 0 + y_0 = y_0$.

Comment: Regarding the uniqueness, the Picard-Lindelof theorem easily guarantees (as a particular case) that linear equation such as this one, with the appropriate number of initial conditions, have one and only one solution. So, if you find a function that satisfies both the initial conditions and the differential equation, it is the only solution of the problem.